Extension of automorphism of shift of finite type
$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$Let $X$ and $Y$ be two subshifts of finite type and $X\subset Y$, and $\phi:X\rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism commuting with the shift map. Is there any homeomorphism $\tilde{\phi}:Y\rightarrow Y$ commuting with the shift map such that $\tilde{\phi}|_X=\phi$?

The two questions are not equivalent. The question asks, denoting $\mathrm{Aut}(Y,X)$ the automorphisms of $Y$ leaving $X$ invariant, whether the restriction map $\mathrm{Aut}(Y,X)\to\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is surjective. When this is true, this map is probably not bijective, and hence it doesn't yield an embedding of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ into $\mathrm{Aut}(Y)$. (By the way, there are several interpretations of "is $\mathrm{Aut}(X)\subset\mathrm{Aut}(Y)$".)

Thank you for your answer. You are right, I edited the question.

Not in general, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452585/extending-isomorphism-between-subsystems-in-shift-system/452710#452710 (a finite shift-invariant set is a subshift of finite type)

@VilleSalo thanks for your answer.  Therefore an automorphism of ${0,1}^{\mathbb{Z}} $ can not be extended to  an automorphism of ${0,1,2}^{\mathbb{Z}} $. Is it true?

I think every automorphism of 2-shift can be extended to 3-shift: kill the dimension rep by composing with shift (which extends), then inerts extend.

Point here being, for a full shift on prime alphabet, the dimension group representation is generated by the shift map.

Very interesting point, thank you so much for sharing it.
